# Enable user to add item to a list dynamically using Django and Ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build functionality into my webapp the does the following:

1. A user searches for an address
2. Nearby cafes are pulled from a database table and displayed to them
3. The user is able to click an "add-to-list"  tag
4. The cafe name/address are added to a list made by the user

I have successfully built 1 and 2. I am struggling with 3 and 4.

**The Current Situation**

I am trying to pass the `cafeName` at this stage via an AJAX post call, but it doesn't look like it is firing correctly. Initially I was trying to do this with AJAX and views.py function but was advised to use Django Rest Framework, so I am now creating an api and using Ajax to pass the cafe details async.

I am currently getting this error when I click a venue name:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/venues/added 400 (Bad Request)
```

**The Code**

At this stage my models.py file looks like this

```
class mapCafes(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    cafe_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_long = models.FloatField()
    cafe_lat = models.FloatField()
    geolocation = models.PointField(geography=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'a_cafes'

class UserList(models.Model):
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #is this okay?

class Venues(models.Model):
    venue_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    venue_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    venue_long = models.FloatField(null=True)
    venue_lat = models.FloatField(null=True)
    venue_geolocation = models.PointField(geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
    user_list = models.ForeignKey(UserList, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #this may need to change to a manytomany model

class VenueList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venues = models.ManyToManyField(Venues)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My project urls look like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('venues/added', views.AddVenueList.as_view()),
    path('venues/create', views.CreateVenueList.as_view()),
]
```

My api app urls look like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('venues/added', views.AddVenueList.as_view()),
    path('venues/create', views.CreateVenueList.as_view()),
]
```

The views.py for the API app looks like this

```
class AddVenueList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = VenueListSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return VenueList.objects.filter(user=user)

class CreateVenueList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = VenueListSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return VenueList.objects.filter(user=user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

And finally the template looks like this (I've stripped the Ajax success function back to simply show console.log at this stage).

```
<div>
            <ul class = "cafe-details">
              {% for cafe in cafes %}
              <li>
                <address>
                  <div>
                      <h6 class="cafe-name">{{ cafe.cafe_name }}</h6>
                      <p >{{ cafe.cafe_address }}</p>
                  </div>
                </address>
                    <p>
                      <a href="">Add to List</a> / <a href="">Recommend</a>
                    </p>
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </div>


            <script>
                const cafeList = document.querySelector(".cafe-details");

                cafeList.addEventListener('click', e => {
                  if (e.target && e.target.matches('a')) {
                    const listItem = e.target.closest('li');
                    var cafeName = listItem.querySelector('.cafe-name').innerText;

                    //Show the cafe name.
                    console.log(cafeName);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                         url : 'api/venues/added',
                         data: {
                           'cafeName': cafeName,
                           'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                          },
                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                          dataType: "json",
                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                          success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                            console.log('User clicked: ' +  data)
                           
                            },
                            failure: function(errMsg) {
                              alert(errMsg);
                            }
                          });
                        };
                      });
            </script>
```

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault();` inside `if (e.target && e.target..` to prevent default behaviour of `a` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This seems to help the async fire, but I am now receiving a 400 error (I updated my OP to show)... any ideas?

Comment: Your data which you are sending to server doesn't look like json ..remove that `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and check onces